# Using Spring MVC 4, when I add Spring Security 3.2 to pom I get ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file error

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-security, java-8

I am using Java 8 in eclipse. Could the issue be that spring security does not support Java 8 as of yet?

```
12:13:44.226 [localhost-startStop-1]   ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\movierental\WEB-INF\classes\com\hemswortht\movierental\annotation\ReleaseYearConstraint.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\movierental\WEB-INF\classes\com\hemswortht\movierental\annotation\ReleaseYearConstraint.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

and ReleaseYearConstraint.java...

```
package com.hemswortht.movierental.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;

import com.hemswortht.movierental.validator.ReleaseYearConstraintValidator;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReleaseYearConstraintValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface ReleaseYearConstraint {
    String message() default "You have specified invalid search input parameters.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Why use security 3.2 with spring 4? I wouldn't mix and match versions. This could easily be your problem.

Comment: @BenThurley: WOuldn't it make sense to stay on GA versions?
As far as I know Spring-Security 4 is still in milestones.!

Different (non-core) spring modules (i.e. security, data, batch) are on diff major versions but have minimum compatible spring-core versions specified. And Spring 4 does support Spring Security 3.2!

Comment: Looks like you solved it

Answer (score 1):

This all boils down to dependencies version management in your build.
I suggest you to take a look at the various solutions Spring offers for that:

- [Spring Framework BOM](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom), for managing spring-framework versions efficiently
- [Spring IO platform BOM](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven) if you want to get version management for spring-framework, spring portfolio projects (so spring security) and even third party dependencies

Note that changing the order of dependencies in your pom does not solve completely your problem - you'd better add dependency exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! So basically you must use Spring 4 if you are using Java 8. Spring Security 3.2 is compatible with Spring 4 so that's ok.

so where did I go wrong?????

You need to make sure the Spring Security 3.2 dependencies COME AFTER the Spring 4 dependencies in the pom. Otherwise all spring versions get resolved to 3.2.6 !!! Doh.